# The “default” version of bash for windows is Ubuntu 14 for me. I'm unable to use Ubuntu 18 in apps like ConEmu/Cmder as a result

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu, cmder

## === Issue ===

I'm attempting to run Ubuntu 18 in ConEmu/Cmder in Windows 10. However, the setup for Cmder says to use this path: `%windir%\system32\bash.exe ~ -cur_console:p` which runs Ubuntu 14. I would like to keep the ubuntu 14 installation, but use the Ubuntu 18 installation by default, instead of Ubuntu 14.

## === Symptoms ===

### # Two versions installed

Running Ubuntu from the start menu, I can choose to run "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" which runs version 14, or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" which is runs version 18

#### Two versions of Ubuntu on start menu

Both of these options bring me to a different version

[image]

#### "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"

The "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" shortcut refers to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~`. This runs version 14. When I launch it and run `lsb-release -a` I get this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
RUNEDOG-HOME%
```

#### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

The "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" Shortcut is some strange Windows "app" and it won't let me see the actual path of the executable. This option runs version 18, here's what I get when I launch it and run `lsb_release -a`

```
➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
➜  ~
```

Note that the prompt is different than the 14 version, `~` vs `HOME%`

### # Default path always runs Ubuntu 14

The default path(s) both give me Ubuntu 14. Assuming those are:

- %windir%\system32\bash.exe
- %windir%\system32\wsl.exe

Those two paths give me the following result with `lsb_release`

```
C:\Users\byron>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe
RUNEDOG-HOME% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
RUNEDOG-HOME% exit

C:\Users\byron>%windir%\system32\bash.exe
RUNEDOG-HOME% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
RUNEDOG-HOME%
```

### # Other Oddities

#### wsl Command gives odd results

`wsl -l --all` only lists Ubuntu 18, but `wsl` runs Ubuntu 14

```
C:\Users\byron>wsl -l --all
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Legacy (Default)
Ubuntu-18.04

C:\Users\byron>wsl
RUNEDOG-HOME% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
RUNEDOG-HOME%
```

#### App Installation in Windows is Odd

Only Ubuntu 18 lists as being installed in Windows:

[image]

Comment: I can tell you.. ***However, the setup for Cmder says to use this path: %windir%\system32\bash.exe ~ -cur_console:p***.  This information either predates the wsl.exe exe or the person who wrote it doesn't know what they are talking about.  Bash.exe will run the default instance.. wsl.exe will let you pick which instance to run.  Also.. the 14.xx installation that doesn't show up with wsl.exe --list is confusing :P

Comment: Compare `where ubuntu` and `dir /b /s /a /ad "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\*Ubuntu*"` and `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\ubuntu.exe"` (run all from an _elevated_ command prompt). Try running all `ubuntu.exe` found (if vary); is any of them version 18 or 14?

Comment: quick note: had to do `where ubuntu1804`, which gives me: `C:\Users\byron\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu1804.exe`

Also, `dir /b /s /a /ad "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\*Ubuntu*"` says `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_2020.1804.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc`

Also, there's nothing like "ubuntu" under that path in the registry.

Regardless, both of the paths I was able to get were Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

Senor CmasMas and JoseFZ clued me in on the issue. Looks like bash.exe is the old way of starting ubuntu on windows, and so it's loading an old version. Instead, this seems to be the correct way to start it:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu1804.exe
```

When I put that into Cmder, it works.

I got that command from: https://waynewerner.com/blog/how-to-use-cmder-ubuntu-1804-on-windows.html